# Plots (ggplot2) in Rmarkdown PDF cropped

Tags: r, ggplot2

Within R I use the ggplot2 plotting library to create plots. I output a bunch of them and also print `\n\n` in between them such that they become their own paragraph in the PDF (via LaTeX). Lately (new R version, I think) the plots started to get cropped in this way:

[image]

The title and the legend are not completely visible, and I do not get why this happens. I am using R 3.6.1 with ggplot2 3.2.1 on Fedora 31. Is there some way to make them readable again?

And this is the whole code:

````
---
title: "Cropping MWE"
author: "Martin Ueding"
date: \today
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
```

We can try it with ggplot2:

```{r}
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'Shape and color of diamonds')
```

And then we can also try it using the built-in plotting.

```{r}
with(diamonds, plot(x, y, main = 'Shape and color of diamonds'))
```

And some more text afterwards.
````

I can change the header to prevent cropping at all, and then it does work.

```
---
title: "Cropping MWE"
author: "Martin Ueding"
date: \today
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_crop: false
---
```

Then however the figures have a bit of stray space around them, which is not perfect either.

Comment: Please also show your rmarkdown chunk options.

Comment: @Gregor: Sure. I have added a minimally working example such that this issue can be diagnosed much easier.